Wordpress, Meta Slider navigation control shows only on first post
I am writing my first custom wordpress theme. When I try to integrate the Meta Slider plugin, it works on every post of my loop, but the navigations are only shown on the first post. I have no Idea where the problem is.
The html of the navigation doesn't seem to get written at all, so I think it is not a CSS problem.
This is my index.php:
get_header();
?>

    <main id="primary" class="site-main">
    <div class="body-content">
        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :

            if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) :
                ?>
                <header>
                    <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                </header>
                <?php
            endif;

            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content' );
                
            endwhile;

            the_posts_navigation();

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>
    </div>

    </main><!-- #main -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();

and this is my content.php:

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
        // Remove the_title() completely to hide the title
        ?>

        <?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></a>
            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php //lea_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
        the_content(
            sprintf(
                wp_kses(
                    /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                    __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'lea' ),
                    array(
                        'span' => array(
                            'class' => array(),
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                // Removed get_the_title() from sprintf() arguments
                ''
            )
        );

        wp_link_pages(
            array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'lea' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            )
        );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article>

I had deleted
get_sidebar(); get_footer();

because i didn't need them, but without them, the navigation didn't show up at all. Maybe the problem has something to do with that?

I discovered, that it only doesn't show my navigation if i post the same slideshow twice. I did this just for trial. On my site each slideshow will be different so my problem has been solved!
